# How can I show that $(R \lor P ) \implies (R \lor Q)$ is equivalent to $R \lor (P \implies Q)$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic

Using logical equivalencies, how can I show that $(R \lor P ) \implies (R \lor Q)$ is equivalent to $R \lor (P \implies Q)$?

For the left side I get:

$\begin{align}(R \lor P ) \implies (R \lor Q) & \iff \lnot(R \lor P) \lor (R \lor Q)\\
& \iff (\lnot R \land \lnot P) \lor (R \lor Q)
\end{align}$

And then I get stuck.

For the right side I just get:

$R \lor (P \implies Q) \iff R \lor (\lnot P \lor Q)$

And then I get stuck.

How can I show that:

$(\lnot R \land \lnot P) \lor (R \lor Q) \iff R \lor (\lnot P \lor Q)$

Comment: Apply [distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement) to the LHS.

Comment: You can use equivalences to convert both expressions to their disjunctive normal form, or both to their conjunctive normal form if you prefer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bridging your work:

\begin{align}
&(\lnot R \land \lnot P) \lor (R \lor Q)\\
&(\lnot R \land \lnot P) \lor R \lor Q\\
&((\lnot R \lor R) \land (\lnot P \lor R)) \lor Q\\
& (\lnot P \lor R) \lor Q\\
& R \lor (\lnot P \lor Q)
\end{align}